# Finding node with max weight that has a size not greater than given limit

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, tree, binary-tree, avl-tree

I am looking at this:

> Suggest a Data Structure to handle shipping boxes where each box has: special ID, weight and size.
>
> From all boxes which have a maximum size of *v* (i.e. `size <= v`) find the heaviest one in *O(log(n))* time, where *n* is the number of total saved boxes.
>
> You may assume that all weights are different.

I want to save those boxes in an AVL tree.

I know that the solution would be sorting the boxes according to their size and saving some extra data in each node, but I'm not sure which data would be helpful.

Example of extra data saved in each node:

- Id of heaviest box in right sub-tree.

## Example

Consider the following AVL tree, where we are looking for the heaviest box whose size is less than 25:

[image]

What kind of information would help decide to go right or left from the root?

---

<sub>* tree was built using: [https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/AVLtree.html](https://www.cs.usfca.edu/%7Egalles/visualization/AVLtree.html)*</sub>

Comment: What will be the order of ```n``` and the number of queries?

Comment: Don’t really think you need a AVLTree here. Heap should suffice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would key your AVL tree by size, and store (and maintain) the *maximum* weight that can be found in a node's subtree, taking into account also the node's own weight.

This will allow to:

- find a path from the root to the spot where a node with size *v* *could* be inserted (without actually doing so). The last node in this path will be the closest predecessor or successor of that potential future node in terms of size.
- from that path (from root to found node) you can filter the nodes that do not have a greater size, and look at the **maximum** weights stored in their left child and at the weight of the node on the path itself. Pick the node with the greatest weight or the subtree with the greatest maximum weight in those candidates. If it is a subtree, walk down the subtree at that node to find the actual node that has this maximised weight. All this consists of one walk down (to find the node with greatest size) and a walk up (along the path) and another one walk down (following a path of equal maximum weight). So it represents a logarithmic time complexity.

The operations on the AVL tree need to be extended so to ensure that the maximum weight is correctly maintained. For instance, when a node is inserted, its weight should bubble up for as long that weight determines the maximum weight stored in an ancestor node. The algorithms for deletions and rotations should be updated to also maintain this extra information in a sound way. But this is all possible without affecting the related time complexities.

### Implementation

This implementation will only focus on finding the desired node. It does not implement the AVL balancing, nor the delete operation. So it is a plain binary tree, with only insertion and lookup features.

I define the following methods on a basic `Node` class that has `size`, `weight` and `maxWeight` properties:

- `pathToSize(size)`: this will find the insertion spot where one could insert a node with the given size as a leaf.
  It returns an array of ancestor nodes that constitute the path from root to the parent below which such a node could be inserted.
- `findHeaviest()`: this will take the `maxWeight` information from the current node and return a node in this node's subtree that matches that weight.
  There are three possibilities:

  - The current node has a weight that matches its `maxWeight`: return it
  - The node's left child has the same `maxWeight`: use recursion to find the node in that subtree.
  - The node's right child has the same `maxWeight`: use recursion to find the node in that subtree.
- `findHeaviestWithMaxSize(size)`: this implements the actual algorithm. It calls `pathToSize(size)` to get a path.
  Then it will look for nodes on that path whose size is not greater than the given size. Otherwise put: these are the
  nodes where the path took a right turn (unless it was the last node on the path). For these nodes we need to check two
  things:

  - does that node itself have a greater weight than we have found so far
  - does that node's left subtree host a node that has a greater weight than we have found so far. We don't have to search that subtree yet, as we can just check against that left child's `maxWeight`.

  After this scan, we know where to look: either we have the node itself, or we have a subtree where we should find a node with that `maxWeight`.
  For the latter case we can use the method `findHeaviest` above.

Below I provide a snippet in JavaScript which allows you to define a binary tree with an input of data pairs, or to just get a random tree with 10 nodes.
You can then change the value of the `size` parameter and see visually (with a little arrow) which node gets selected that has a size that is not greater and maximises the weight.

Obviously the snippet has some code for the user-interface, but the core is in the above mentioned methods of the `Node` class.

```js
class Node {
    constructor(size, weight) {
        this.size = size;
        this.weight = weight;
        this.left = null;
        this.right = null;
        this.maxWeight = weight;
    }
    pathToSize(size) {
        // Find a path to a node that would be the parent if 
        //   a new node were added with the given size.
        let child = size < this.size ? this.left : this.right;
        if (child === null) return [this];
        // Use recursion to add the rest of the path
        return [this, ...child.pathToSize(size)];
    }
    findHeaviest() {
        // Find a decendant that has a weight equal to the maxWeight of this node
        if (this.weight === this.maxWeight) return this;
        // As it is not this node that has that weight, it must be found
        // in the left or the right subtree:
        if (this.left !== null && this.left.maxWeight === this.maxWeight) {
            return this.left.findHeaviest();
        } else if (this.right !== null && this.right.maxWeight === this.maxWeight) {
            return this.right.findHeaviest();
        }
        throw "tree is inconsistent";
    }
    findHeaviestWithMaxSize(size) {
        let path = this.pathToSize(size);
        // All nodes that have a size up to the given size are represented by this path, as follows:
        // If a node on the path has a size that is not greater, then: 
        //    that node itself and its complete left subtree is in that collection.
        // The union of those collections has all nodes with a size up to the given size.
        // So we will now find where in those collections we have the heaviest node.
        let maxWeight = -Infinity; // The greatest weight we can find among valid nodes
        let bestTree = null; // subtree with heaviest node
        for (let node of path) {
            if (node.size > size) continue; // skip this node
            // Check the weight(!) of the current node:
            if (node.weight > maxWeight) {
                maxWeight = node.weight; // not its maxWeight!!
                bestTree = node;
            }
            // Check the maxWeight(!) of the left subtree
            node = node.left;
            if (node !== null && node.maxWeight > maxWeight) {
                maxWeight = node.maxWeight;
                bestTree = node;
            }
        }
        if (bestTree === null) return null; // there is no such node
        // Get the node with that maxWeight in the identified node/subtree 
        if (bestTree.weight === maxWeight) return bestTree;
        return bestTree.findHeaviest();
    }
    toString(node) {
        // Provide a string representation of this tree
        let left = [];
        let right = [];
        if (this.left !== null) left = this.left.toString(node).split("\n");
        if (this.right !== null) right = this.right.toString(node).split("\n");
        let leftWidth = left[0]?.length || 0;
        let rightWidth = right[0]?.length || 0;
        let width = leftWidth + 5 + rightWidth;
        let lines = Array.from({length: Math.max(left.length, right.length)}, (_, i) =>
            (left[i] || " ".repeat(leftWidth)) + "     " + (right[i] || ""));
        if (lines.length) {
            lines.unshift(
                (leftWidth ? left[0].replace(/\S.*/, "┌").padEnd(leftWidth+2, "─") : " ".repeat(leftWidth+2))
                 + "┴┘└"[!leftWidth * 2 + !rightWidth]
                 + (rightWidth ? right[0].replace(/.*\S/, "┐").padStart(rightWidth+2, "─") : " ".repeat(rightWidth+2))
            );
            lines.unshift("│".padStart(leftWidth+3).padEnd(width));
        }
        lines.unshift((String(this.weight).padStart(4, "0") + "g").padStart(leftWidth+5).padEnd(width));
        lines.unshift((String(this.size).padStart(4, "0") + "m").padStart(leftWidth+5).padEnd(width));
        lines.unshift((node === this ? "▼" : "│").padStart(leftWidth+3).padEnd(width));
        return lines.join("\n");
    }
}

class Tree {
    constructor() {
        this.root = null;
        // Only needed for this demo:
        // for exporting the insertions that are made
        this.array = []; 
    }
    add(size, weight) {
        this.array.push([size, weight]);
        if (this.root === null) {
            this.root = new Node(size, weight);
            return;
        }
        let path = this.root.pathToSize(size);
        let parent = path.pop();
        if (size < parent.size) {
            parent.left = new Node(size, weight);
        } else {
            parent.right = new Node(size, weight);
        }
        // Adjust weight of ancestors
        while (parent !== undefined && parent.maxWeight < weight) {
            parent.maxWeight = weight;
            parent = path.pop();
        }
    }
    toString(markedNode) {
        if (this.root === null) return "";
        return this.root.toString(markedNode);
    }
    findHeaviestWithMaxSize(size) {
        if (this.root === null) return null;
        return this.root.findHeaviestWithMaxSize(size);
    }
    static from(arr) {
        let tree = new Tree;
        for (let pair of arr) {
            tree.add(...pair);
        }
        return tree;
    }
}

let tree = new Tree;

// I/O handling below:

let inpJson = document.getElementById("json");
let inpSize = document.getElementById("size");
let inpWeight = document.getElementById("weight");
let btnCreate = document.getElementById("create");
let output = document.querySelector("pre");

function refresh() {
    let node = tree.findHeaviestWithMaxSize(+inpSize.value);
    output.textContent = tree.toString(node);
    json.value = JSON.stringify(tree.array);
}

function load() {
    let array;
    try {
        array = JSON.parse(json.value);
    } catch {
        return;
    }
    tree = Tree.from(array);
    refresh();
}

inpJson.addEventListener("input", load);
inpSize.addEventListener("input", refresh);

btnCreate.addEventListener("click", function() {
    tree = randomTree();
    refresh();
});

function randBetween(a, b) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * (b - a + 1) + a);
}

function randPair() {
    return [randBetween(0, 10), randBetween(0, 10)];
}

function randomTree() {
    let array = Array.from({length: 10}, randPair);
    return Tree.from(array);
}

load();
```

```css
#json { width: 100% }
#size { width: 3em }
```

```html
JSON with [size, weight] pairs, in insertion order:<br>
<input id="json" value="[[6,8],[4,1],[8,10],[5,5],[7,5],[9,6],[5,9],[6,7],[8,6]]"><br>
<button id="create">Randomise</button><br>
<hr>
Find heaviest node with size at most: <input id="size" type="number" value="5">m<br>
<pre>
</pre>
```

To better enjoy this snippet, make sure to enlarge it with the "Full Page" link, once you have it running.

Comment: Hi, much thanks for your answer but I disagree that this type of info would be able to help determining which direction to go, "find the node with the greatest size that is not greater than a given v." how can you do this?

Comment: Well, that is the easy part. That is standard for how AVL trees work. They are binary search trees, so you go to the right as long as the node's size is smaller, and to the left when it is greater. If in the latter case, there is no left child, you backtrack to the first node that has a lesser size. That determines the end of a root-to-node path. Then the second phase starts to look for the greatest weight. I don't have time to provide code for this, as this is quite a job: it needs to cover insertion, deletion, rotation, retrieval, ...

Comment: This can't be done in O(log n): "and walk down the subtree at that node to find the actual node that has this maximised weight" the tree isn't sorted by weight

Comment: @john, it can be: we don't rely on any sorting for the weight. When you are at a node and want to find the node with the weight that corresponds to the max weight registered in that node, you have 3 possibilities: either it is that node itself (easy to check) or it is in the left subtree, in which case that left child *also* has that same registered max weight, or it is in the right subtree (same reasoning). So you *can* choose the path to find it.

Comment: I added a more detailed description of the different phases, and an implementation in JavaScript which you can run here. It is interactive so that you can produce a random tree (or encode an insertion sequence with JSON notation) and then provide a size-input to see which node gets selected in a visual representation of the tree.

Comment: what if you are searching for weight 20 where max weight for left son is 22 and for right son in 23? you can't decide where to go

Comment: @john, I am not sure what you mean. This algorithm doesn't search for a specific weight. It looks at a selected node (which is within the size limit), checks what its `maxWeight` property has, and then looks for *that* weight. In that case the children of that node will never have a *greater* `maxWeight` than that. It can be equal or less. The algorithm chooses the child where it is equal. If you have a counter example, please run the snippet, enter it (in the JSON box), and see what it does.

Comment: Any other feed-back?

Comment: You did a great job! THANKS A LOT, I never meet someone like you here :)

Comment: Nice to hear ;-)